# c# two path glued together don't work in ftp request.DownloadData

Tags: c#

```
        string slink = "\\README.TXT";
        string ipath = "C:\\Users\\Crystal\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\workspace\\workspace\\bin\\Debug";
        string test = lpath+"\\workspace\\"+slink;
        string test1 = "C:\\Users\\Crystal\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\workspace\\workspace\\bin\\Debug\\workspace\\README.TXT";
        string ftpfullpath = myUri.ToString();
        WebClient request = new WebClient();
        FileStream file = File.Create(@test);
```

if i  write  `FileStream file = File.Create(@test);`  i get error illegal characters.
if i write `FileStream file = File.Create(@test1);`  it works!

i think something is wrong with gluing multiple string path values. i've tried  also `Path.Combine` but also doesn't work

Comment: Did you look at your string in the debugger?

Comment: the problem is that you `test` contains two \\ (one from the end of  `"\\workspace\\"` and one from the beginning of `slink`)...

Comment: FYI, you don't need to write `@test`. You only need the `@` for identifiers that would otherwise be illegal in C#, such as `@class`.

Comment: @Gabe: He thinks it's an `@`-string

Comment: @SLaks: I considered that, but since he already has double-backslashes, I didn't think that theory made much sense.

Comment: tnx all

I've solved it because slinki has  invisible "/r" at and!!!!!  now works!!

Answer (score 2):

In your third line of code, you've used lpath instead of ipath - i am assuming that's a typo

Use this:

```
string resultPath= Path.Combine(p1, p2);
```

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: [Check the invalid characters that might be causing the problem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Taking it that `lpath` is a typo for `ipath`, the latter adds an extra slash (or set of slashes, depending on the context) before `README.TXT`.

That is to say,

```
\\workspace\\README.TXT
```

becomes,

```
\\workspace\\\\README.TXT
```

Comment: Extra backslashes should not be a problem because they get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing `"..\\" + "\\..."`.

A path cannot have two consecutive `\`s.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem: `File.Create("c:\\\\foo\\\\file1.xml");` will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your either your slink or your test.  The code you have ends up with the following path:

```
C:\Users\Crystal\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\workspace\workspace\bin\Debug\workspace\\README.TXT
```

Notice the double slash before README.TXT?

This is caused because slink becomes:

```
\README.TXT
```

Then you are trying to combine that with:

```
C:\Users\Crystal\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\workspace\workspace\bin\Debug\workspace\
```

You can do 1 of 2 things to fix the problem:

1. Remove the \\ from the slink
2. Remove the trailing \\ from the "\\workspace\\" when you try to combine them

I would suggest option 1 - it clearly separates the filename from the path of the file.  Having the \\ preceding the file implies that the filename also has its path info

Comment: i debug with  
a=Path.combine(lpath,"workspace")
b= Path.combine(a,slinki);  ---- here i get erorr illegal chars..

in debug on erorr a = "C:\\Users\\Crystal\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\workspace\\workspace\\bin\\Debug\\workspace"
b = "README.TXT\r"
also tried  slinki = slinki.replace(@"\","");